# Is there any way to exclude products on assigned collection in the Collections page on Shopify?

Tags: collections, shopify

Is there any way to exclude products on assigned collection in the Collections page on Shopify? I'm quite new to shopify so I'm struggling with this part.

Comment: is the collection automatic or manual, if automatic add tags to exclude from the collection, or if manual then removes them from the backend?

Comment: It is automatic. Like the ones showing in domain.com/collections/all

Comment: /collections/all is the default. collection from Shopify that include all the products. If don't want to show products or render this page. simply add a redirect into backend settings to the homepage. but you can't exclude products from listing into this collection.